# Flickering horizontal static lines in display

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

I have Dell Inspiron 15 Intel N5050 laptop around one year old.When I started my laptop yesterday I saw Flickering horizontal static lines in display and it seems continuously at present time. What's the reasons for this?

Comment: Try it in safe mode.  If it's OK there something may have gotten mucked up in your display refresh settings, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Horizontal lines flash randomly over laptop display](http://superuser.com/questions/773911/horizontal-lines-flash-randomly-over-laptop-display)

Answer (score 1):

### Change your Power Plan settings

The power plan is limiting the resources for the graphics card to function properly. Change all the settings to the Maximum Performance.

**How I fixed the problem:**

- Install the latest drivers from the official AMD website (Catalyst 14.0+).
- Change you Power Plan to High Performance (in battery and plugged-in).
- Go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change advanced power settings> ATI Graphics Power Settings> ATI Powerplay settings> On battery, Plugged in: **Maximum Performance**.
- Go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change advanced power settings> PCI Express> Link State Power Management> On battery, Plugged in: **Off**.
- Disable Aero (Choose the *Windows 7 Basic* theme)
- Restart your PC.

**Important:** This will also fix a constant change in the brightness level when you switch between dark and bright apps.

Answer (score 0):

Are the lines visible in the BIOS as well. If the answer is yes then your display possibly has an issue or else you can also perform a screen test to double check the same. I found this [article](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?docid=266529) as well which is related to your issue on Dell Support.

Hope it helps. Cheers !!